# Error al quere Saber si un numero es Positivo o Negativo utilizando recursividad indirecta

Tags: java, recursión

Estoy haciendo el siguiente ejercicio, la tarea a realizar es saber si un numero es **Positivo o Negativo** utilizando recursividad indirecta, el código compila pero siempre me devuelve `True` ¿qué debería corregir?

```
public class EjercicioTrece {
    public static void main (String[]args){
        System.out.println(esPositivo(4));
        System.out.println(esNegativo(-1));
        System.out.println(esNegativo(4));
        System.out.println(esPositivo(-2));
    }
    public static boolean esPositivo(int num){
        if(num>0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return esNegativo(num);
        }
    }
    public static boolean esNegativo(int num){
        if(num<0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return esPositivo(num);
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

tecDeProg.EjercicioTrece

```
true
true
true
true
Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

Comment: Normal que te salga eso, si sigues la traza del programa llamas al primer metodo que te dice si es positivo, de serlo escribe true, de no serlo llama a la funcion negativo, la cual si el numero es negativo devolvera true tambien xD

Comment: que es recursividad indirecta?

Answer (score -1):

```
    public class EjercicioTrece {
    public static void main (String[]args){
        System.out.println(esPositivo(4));
        System.out.println(esNegativo(-1));
        System.out.println(esNegativo(4));
        System.out.println(esPositivo(-2));
    }
    public static boolean esPositivo(int num){
        if(num>0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return !esNegativo(num);
        }
    }
    public static boolean esNegativo(int num){
        if(num<0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return !esPositivo(num);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Solo necesitabas negar el return del else :)

Comment: Deberías de incluir una explicación a el por que esa solución. Solo el código no ayuda mucho a entender.